# Can't step over when using GoClipse

Tags: debugging, go, goclipse

This is a duplicate question from [How to debug Go programs using GoClipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561329/how-to-debug-go-programs-using-goclipse), however that thread only answered one of the two questions posed by the poster.

When I debug my program with GoClipse, the "step over" command is functioning exactly the same as the "step into" command.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: From: https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#debugger-issues 

"Try to reproduce the problem outside of Eclipse, using just the command-line GDB interface. If the problem also occurs there, then it's an issue in either GDB or the Go compiler tools, not GoClipse. For more info on how to use command-line GDB, see http://golang.org/doc/gdb."

Unfortunately if the problem also occurs when running GDB directly, it's likely a bug or limitation with the Go toolchain's debugging support, so there is not much Goclipse can do.

Comment: Thank you Bruno, it was definitely an issue with gdb.

I'm not sure why, but gdb doesn't seem to respect my breakpoints at all. After poking around, I ultimately gave up on the possibility of a modern debugging experience with Go - I sank several hours into trying to correctly configure gdb for Go and got nowhere. I did find a useful debugger (written in Go!) called godebug, which offers the best experience I've seen so far.