# Enabling breakpoints in goclipse

Tags: eclipse, go, gdb, goclipse

I'm trying to get debugging of go programs working in eclipse Luna with goclipse v0.11.0 on OS-X 10.9.5. I am using GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1 from brew, and go1.4.2.

I successfully installed and code-signed `gdb` using instructions here:

http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/

I am building my go program with `-gcflags "-N -l"` and I can successfully debug it at the command line, including setting breakpoints at go functions and stepping through them with the `gdb` command line, with source appearing as it should.

However, in goclipse I cannot set a breakpoint at all, because the 'toggle breakpoint' item on the menu is greyed out, and the 'Breakpoint Types' list says 'none available'.

If I select 'Stop on Startup at' 'main', then I can step through assembler, which is unhelpful, but proves gdb is being used.

If I keep the above option set, wait until the program hits the `main` breakpoint, and type (at the gdb console within eclipse) `break main.foo`, then `cont`, then a breakpoint is set in the right place, and I can step through things in the Eclipse IDE. Thus it appears the only issue is *setting* the breakpoints in the IDE.

The go program concerned is a single file and it works under command line gdb, and I have deleted the binary and started afresh, so this is not a 'need a rebuild' issue.

Related question: [How to debug Go programs using GoClipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24561329/how-to-debug-go-programs-using-goclipse) however the two answers there are 'disable Stop on Startup' (which makes no difference here), and ensuring `-gcflags "-N -l"` is given (which makes no difference).

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of breakpoints not being available]

Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to be a genuine Goclipse issue. Can you open a bug report please: https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md . I'm particularly interested in the Eclipse Error Log and Configuration Log. (You can use https://gist.github.com/ to attach large files)

Comment: @BrunoMedeiros thanks - filed as https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/issues/135 with an error log excerpt, but no configuration log as I'm not sure how to find that.